Inconsistency in scattering length of spherical well potential
I'm trying to understand the scattering length of the spherical well potential
$$V(r)=\begin{cases}-V_0&r<r_0\\ 0&r>r_0\end{cases}$$
The $V_0>0$ (attractive) case is fairly well documented in various lecture notes (for example: https://muellergroup.lassp.cornell.edu/scatter.pdf), and it's clear that
$$a_s\equiv\lim_{k\to0}-\frac{\tan\delta_k}{k}=-\frac{\tan \left(\sqrt{\frac{2 V_0 m}{\hbar^2}} r_0\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{2 V_0 m}{\hbar^2}}}$$
For $V_0<0$, it's a bit tricky but still solvable. In fact, an analytic continuation works perfectly for that. The results gives $a_s<0$ for all $V_0$ and when $|V_0|\to\infty$ we have $a_s\to0^-$.
However, by pushing $V_0\to-\infty$, one also found this is equivalent to the hard wall potential, and $\delta_k=-kr_0$ which gives a finite $a_s=r_0>0$. How to understand the two contradict answers?

You forgot the extra $+r_0$ in your formula for $a_s$. Check out (44) in your linked lecture notes

@LPZ I see, thanks. It turns out I used $\tan(\delta_k+kr_0)$ instead of $\tan(\delta_k)$ and omitted $kr_0$ first by taking the $k\to0$ limit while the reality is they have the same order of $k$.
